# Projection in Azure table services october 2012 version without using string to refer to the column

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

In the previous version of of the table storage API, we had to use contexts and a `new` expression to handle projection on the server side to save bandwidth:

```
var result =
    GetContext().CreateQuery<MyEntity>(TABLENAME)
    .Where(...)
    .Select(e => new { e.ColumnToProject }) //convenient to have the real reference to the entity's properties here
    .AsTableServiceQuery().ToList().Select(ee => ee.ColumnToProject);
```

In [this guide](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#header-14) for the october 2012 API, microsoft is using a DynamicTableEntity with an EntityResolver to handle projection. The syntax is unecessarily complex and the words thing is you need to use a string to refer to the column name.

```
var result =
    tableReference.ExecuteQuery(
        new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
            .Where(...)
            .Select(new[] {"ColumnToProject"}),
        (key, rowKey, timestamp, properties, etag) => 
            properties["ColumnToProject"].GuidValue) //lets say ColumnToProject contains a guid in this example
    .ToList()
```

Is there a prettier way to do projection with the new API version? Especially so that I can use real references to the column names and not a string, which is pretty inconvenient and easy to forget if the property names are changed in the entity later.

Comment: I am using a class with static fields / get{} statements in lieu of hard coding strings.

Comment: I am too, but that just moves the problem. Changing the property name in the entity does not change the static fields.

Comment: I am wondering something similar => I want to implement an ITableEntity-based class with a few required properties and a dynamic collection that can be accessed like DynamicTableEntity properties. I think doing this means overriding the ITableEntity.ReadEntity and ITableEntity.WriteEntity methods, but I cannot find any examples of this to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like it. (I found your question while looking for a prettier way myself)

According to the teamblog entry describing the changes;

> Note, for this release we have not provided an IQueryable
>   implementation, so developers who are migrating applications to the
>   2.0 release and wish to leverage the new table implementation will need to reconstruct their queries using the provided syntax.

[Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.0 Tables Deep Dive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx)